# Overlap operator for simple ( regex-like ) Patterns

Tags: regular-language, proofs, string-matching

( *Introduction* )

Some Notation

- lower case letters, $a, b, c$ will be used to denote single symbols
- Upper case letters, $P, Q, R$ will be used to denote string of symbols
- $a\!:\!S$ means a string starting with a symbol, $a$ and ending with the string $S$

I'm currently formulating a simple form of regex-like patterns defined as follows

*Given*

- An alphabet, $\Sigma$, st. $\{ ?, * \} \notin \Sigma$

*Define*

- A pattern over $\Sigma$ to be an element of $( \Sigma\ \cup\ \{ ?, * \})^*$
- $\bar\Sigma = \Sigma\ \cup\ \{?\}$
- $r(\Sigma) = ( \Sigma\ \cup\ \{ ?, * \})^*$

( $.^*$ denotes to Kleene star operator )

Define the match operator, $M_s$, recursively as

$$
\forall S \in \Sigma^*.\ \forall P \in r(\Sigma).\ \forall a \in \Sigma.\ \forall \bar{a} \in \bar{\Sigma}.\ \begin{cases}
M_s( & \epsilon &, & \epsilon & )\  = &  \text{Accept} \\
M_s( & \epsilon &, & \bar{a}:P & )\  = &  \text{Reject} \\
M_s( & \epsilon &, & *:P & )\ = & M_s( \epsilon, P ) \\
M_s( & a:S &, & \epsilon & )\ = & \text{Reject} \\
M_s( & a:S &, & \bar{a}:P & )\ = &
\begin{cases}
M(a,\bar{a}) & M_s( S, P ) \\
\text{otherwise} & \text{Reject}
\end{cases}\\
M_s( & a:S &, & *:P & )\ = & M_s( S, *:P )\ \vee\ M_s( a:S, P ) 
\end{cases}
$$

where

$$M(a,b) \equiv ( a = b ) \vee ( a = ? ) \vee ( b = ? )$$

In simple terms, a pattern matches a string if the pattern can be transformed into the string by:

- Substituting $?$ for any character
- Substituting $*$ for any sequence ( including empty ) of characters

---

( *Question* )

I would like to define an overlap operator, $M_p$, which given two patterns can return:

- No Overlap
- *Overlap, but neither are a subset of each other*
- left is a subset of right
- right is a subset of left
- both patterns are equal

Ideally this operator would be defined in such a way that it can be efficiently implemented as well.

---

( *My attempt* )

$$
\forall P, Q \in r(\Sigma).\ \forall \bar{a}, \bar{b} \in \bar{\Sigma}.\
\begin{cases}
M_p( & \epsilon &, & \epsilon & )\  = &  \text{Accept} \\
M_p( & \bar{a}:P &, & \epsilon & )\  = &  \text{Reject} \\
M_p( & *:P &, & \epsilon & )\ = & M_p( P, \epsilon ) \\
M_p( & \epsilon &, & \bar{b}:Q & ) \ = &  \text{Reject} \\
M_p( & \epsilon &, & *:Q & )\ = & M_p( \epsilon, Q ) \\
M_p( & \bar{a}:P &, & \bar{b}:Q & )\ = &
\begin{cases}
M(\bar{a},\bar{b}) & M_p( P, Q ) \\
\text{otherwise} & \text{Reject}
\end{cases}\\
M_p( & \bar{a}:P &, & *:Q & )\ = & M_p( P, *:Q )\ \vee\ M_p( \bar{a}:P, Q ) \\
M_p( & *:P &, & \bar{b}:Q & )\ = & M_p( P, \bar{b}:Q )\ \vee\ M_p( *:P, Q ) \\
M_p( & *:P &, & *:Q & )\ = & M_p( P, *:Q )\ \vee\ M_p( *:P, Q )
\end{cases}
$$

This function only gives whether the patterns have overlap. Also I'm unsure how to formally and rigorously show that this operator is correct.